# Como integrar CDI-Unit com Jersey Test Framework?

Tags: java, rest, cdi, junit, jersey

Olá.

Estou trabalhando em um ws rest com CDI e Jersey. Quero criar uma unidade de testes com JUnit e devido ao CDI acabei usando o Runner CDI-Unit. Achei o CDI-Unit mais simples que o WeldJUnit4Runner.

Agora, preciso adicionar o Jersey Test Framework para realizar os testes de alguns recursos que serão consumidos. Mas não estou sabendo como integrar o Jersey Test Framework ao CDI-Unit.

Tenho a seguinte exceção ao executar um teste qualquer:

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.UnproxyableResolutionException: WELD-001437: 
Normal scoped bean class rest.resource.ContactResourceTest is not proxyable because the type is final or 
it contains a final method public final javax.ws.rs.client.
WebTarget org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest.target() - unknown javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Bean instance.
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Proxies.getUnproxyableClassException(Proxies.java:214)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Proxies.getUnproxyableTypeException(Proxies.java:178)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Proxies.getUnproxyableTypeException(Proxies.java:140)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider.getClientProxy(ClientProxyProvider.java:231)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:736)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.InstanceImpl.getBeanInstance(InstanceImpl.java:179)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.InstanceImpl.get(InstanceImpl.java:99)
    at org.jglue.cdiunit.CdiRunner.createTest(CdiRunner.java:156)
    at org.jglue.cdiunit.CdiRunner.createTest(CdiRunner.java:138)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:266)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:263)
    at org.jglue.cdiunit.CdiRunner.methodBlock(CdiRunner.java:164)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Será que é possível integra-los? Não achei nem exemplo sobre esses dois carinhas trabalhando juntos. A propósito, preciso do CDI nos testes porque algumas classe de recursos possuem a anotação @Inject para a injeção de services.

```java
@RunWith(CdiRunner.class)
@AdditionalClasses({LoggerProducerUtil.class})
@ActivatedAlternatives(JPATest.class)
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class ContactResourceTest extends JerseyTest {

    @Inject
    private AuthenticationService service;
    private Client client;

    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig(
                ContactResource.class);
    }

    // @Test omitidos   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não consegui resolver o problema com o CDI-Unit, mas consegui executar os testes que queria da seguinte forma.
Estendi o Jersey na classe de testes e precisei então configurar um AbstractBuilder para fazer o Bind entre os beans que injetáveis que fazem parte dos recursos que seriam testados.

```
public class CustomerResourceTest extends JerseyTest {

    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig()
                .packages(true, "br.com.devmedia.crudrest.resource")
                .register(new AbstractBinder() {
                    @Override
                    protected void configure() {
                        bind(CustomerServiceImpl.class).to(CustomerService.class);
                        bindFactory(EntityManagerFactoryTest.class).to(EntityManagerFactory.class);
                        bindFactory(EntityManagerTest.class).to(EntityManager.class);
                    }
                });
    } 

    // testes aqui  
}
```

Já as classes EntityManagerFactoryTest e EntityManagerTest eu criei dentro da própria unidade de testes, para que meu entityManager na aplicação fosse injetado nos Dao's.

```
public class EntityManagerFactoryTest implements Factory<EntityManagerFactory> {

    private final EntityManagerFactory factory;

    public EntityManagerFactoryTest() {
        factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JPAUtilTest");
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(EntityManagerFactory factory) {
        factory.close();
    }

    @Override
    public EntityManagerFactory provide() {
        return factory;
    }
}

public class EntityManagerTest implements Factory<EntityManager> {

    private final EntityManagerFactory factory;
    private final CloseableService closeService;

    @Inject
    public EntityManagerTest(EntityManagerFactory factory, CloseableService closeService) {
        this.factory = factory;
        this.closeService = closeService;
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(EntityManager entityManager) {
        if (entityManager != null && entityManager.isOpen()) {
            entityManager.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public EntityManager provide() {
        final EntityManager entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();
        this.closeService.add(new Closeable(){
            @Override
            public void close() {
                entityManager.close();
            }
        });
        return entityManager;
    }
}
```

Dessa forma consegui realizar os testes usando CDI para injetar o service no recurso Jersey.